# Android CheckBox remains state after destroy

Tags: android, android-activity

I do have a very simple application with just a single CheckBox. I thought that when android does destroy my activity the state of this checkbox will be list. What actually happens is, that the checkbox keeps checked.

The onDestroy() is actually called (on rotation or when I switch to another app -> my emulator has this dev configuration).

So why does this work without using onRestoreInstanceState() and onSaveInstanceState()?

Android Target is 4.2 Jelly Bean.

Here my Activity:

```
public class CoffeeMixerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_coffee_mixer);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.d("MyMessage", "Destroy my app");
}
}
```

Here my Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".CoffeeMixerActivity" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBoxSprinkles"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sprinkles" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. found the solution by myself:
[Android CheckBox -- Restoring State After Screen Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512010/android-checkbox-restoring-state-after-screen-rotation)

Description:
Every View does have the android:saveEnabled flag on true.. which means that when the View does have an ID the state is automatically saved when the view is freezed...

Here there attribute documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#saveEnabled