# CheckBox State preservation not working

Tags: android, checkbox

I have used android CheckBox and current state is checked when I rotate the screen checked state is changed to unchecked.

I have attached the code:

```
 CheckBox check = new CheckBox(this);
 check.Text = "CheckBox";
 linearLayout.AddView(check);
```

Please find the screen shot:
Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

How to restrict this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from below link

[Android CheckBox -- Restoring State After Screen Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512010/android-checkbox-restoring-state-after-screen-rotation)

"Solution were to disable 'restoring instance state':

```
<RadioButton
...
android:saveEnabled="false" />
```

"

Since you're creating the checkmark programatically, you may be able to do:

```
check.saveEnabled = false;
```